# confusion matrix format after converting to json results using python

Tags: python, json, confusion-matrix

My confusion matrix code will be like this

```
confusionmatrix = pd.DataFrame(
    confusion_matrix(test["Churn"], predictions),
    columns=["Predicted False", "Predicted True"], index=["Actual False", "Actual True"]
    )
```

I am getting results like this

```
Predicted False  Predicted True
Actual False              877             100
Actual True               183             179
```

After i converted this above confusion matrix results to json. My json results would be like this

```
results = [{'confusionmatrix' : confusionmatrix}]

final = pd.Series(results).to_json(orient='records')

[
    {
        "confusionmatrix": [
            {
                "Predicted False": 877,
                "Predicted True": 100
            },
            {
                "Predicted False": 183,
                "Predicted True": 179
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But, my expected output need to be like this,

```
[
    {
        "confusionmatrix": [
            {
                "Actual": "False",
                "Predict": "False",
                "value": 894
            },
            {
                "Actual": "False",
                "Predict": "True",
                "value": 125
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Where can i change my code for getting results like this?

Comment: your expected format is not a valid json format [verify with this link](https://jsonlint.com/), I don't even understand what kind of data structure is this

Comment: That is given for sample. kindly check the updated result

Comment: @ Pratik Kumar  how can i get results like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(test["Churn"], predictions), 
                  columns=["False", "True"], 
                  index=["False", "True"])
df.index.name= 'Actual'
df.columns.name= 'Predicted'
print (df)
Predicted  False  True
Actual                
False        877   183
True         100   179

confusionmatrix = df.unstack().rename('value').reset_index()
print (confusionmatrix)
  Predicted Actual  value
0     False  False    877
1     False   True    100
2      True  False    183
3      True   True    179

results = [{'confusionmatrix' : confusionmatrix}]

final = pd.Series(results).to_json(orient='records')
print (final)
[{"confusionmatrix":[{"Predicted":"False","Actual":"False","value":877},
                     {"Predicted":"False","Actual":"True","value":100},
                     {"Predicted":"True","Actual":"False","value":183},
                     {"Predicted":"True","Actual":"True","value":179}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you @ jezrael

Comment: Now I am offline, on phone only. So the best is create for each problem separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692459/multiple-model-accuracy-json-result-format-using-python