# how to order the json format data with in the arrary using python

Tags: python, arrays, json

i have grouped the set of results and trying to convert that results to python with to_json method.

This is my code to convert my results to json. The results variable contains all the results.

```
results =  {'main_category' : {'total_count' : total_count,'total_predicted_postive_count' : total_predicted_postive_count, 'total_predicted_negative_count' : total_predicted_negative_count ,
                 'total_predicted_postive_rate' : total_predicted_postive_rate, 'total_predicted_negative_rate' : total_predicted_negative_rate, 'high_predicted_positive_region' : high_predicted_positive_region, 
                 'model_accuracy' : model_accuracy } }, { 'category' : [{ 'subcategory' : 'gender'}, [{'subcategory_name' : [{ 'subcategory_name' : 'male', 'churn_count' : male_churn_count, 'churn_rate' : male_churn_rate, 'retention_count' : male_retention_count,
                 'retention_rate' : male_retention_rate }] }] ] }

    overall_results = pd.Series(results).to_json(orient='records') 
    print(overall_results)
```

After i convert this to json, my output will be like this

```
[
    {
        "main_category": {
            "high_predicted_positive_region": 564,
            "total_predicted_postive_count": 1481,
            "model_accuracy": 1,
            "total_predicted_postive_rate": 0.2212429041,
            "total_predicted_negative_rate": 0.7787570959,
            "total_count": 7032,
            "total_predicted_negative_count": 5213
        }
    },
    {
        "category": [
            {
                "subcategory": "gender"
            },
            [
                {
                    "subcategory_name": [
                        {
                            "churn_rate": 0.106363908,
                            "churn_count": 712,
                            "retention_count": 2658,
                            "subcategory_name": "male",
                            "retention_rate": 0.3970720048
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

But my expected output format should be like this

```
[
    {
        "main_category": {
            "high_predicted_positive_region": 564,
            "total_predicted_postive_count": 1481,
            "model_accuracy": 1,
            "total_predicted_postive_rate": 0.2212429041,
            "total_predicted_negative_rate": 0.7787570959,
            "total_count": 7032,
            "total_predicted_negative_count": 5213
        }
    },
    {
        "category": [
            {
                "subcategory": "gender"
            },
            [
                {
                    "subcategory_name": [
                        {
                            "subcategory_name": "male",
                            "churn_count": 712,
                            "churn_rate": 0.106363908,
                            "retention_count": 2658,
                            "retention_rate": 0.3970720048
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

inside the array of subcategory name, whatever order i mentioned in the results, it should display. But i am getting in a mixed order.

Where should i change according to that order. Any other way to get this same result format.

Comment: @jezrael please help me out for this issue

Comment: Maybe you can skip `pandas` and head over to [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Probably, if you need to deal with ordered items in JSON, you need to use a more proper data structure. 'An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pair'

Comment: any one can give sample example for my above data

Comment: i am using to_json function ordered dict is not working here

Answer (score 1):

In Python, dictionaries are not ordered. If you want to preserve the insertion order, you need to use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

It seems you're using Pandas. I don't know much about it, but [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752819/pandas-dataframe-from-dict-not-preserving-order-using-ordereddict) will help you further with using OrderedDicts in Pandas.

Comment: AFAIU, the OP needs to preserve order in the final JSON for further computations.

Answer (score 0):

The json.dumps() has a sorted key that when set to True will output a sorted json output.
You could insert a json.dumps() call with  sorted=True. (not sure what orient='records' does but you would lose this).

Be warned though that this will not work on python3 as the mixed-mode < operator has been removed and you will get an error if your keys have different types.

Generally dicts are unordered...

Otherwise you must write your own dict parser....